# Can I perform elementary line operations to $\det(A-\lambda I)$ like this?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I have a $4 \times 4$ matrix:

$$A =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
        4 & -2 & 0 & -3\\
        8 & -1 & 2 & 1\\
        1 & 0 & 3 & 4\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

I want to find the eigenvalues so I have to solve $\det(A - \lambda I)$. Can I perform line operations to $A$ before I subtract its diagonal with $\lambda$?

Is there any good online calculator that shows the steps of finding the determinant, eigenvalues etc?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Row operations won't preserve eigenvalues; you can transform the identity matrix into any other invertible matrix, but not all invertible matrices have only $1$s as eigenvalues.

Comment: No, in general performing row operations on $A$ will alter its characteristic polynomial.  Otherwise, every matrix would have the same eigenvalues as its reduced row echelon form, which is certainly not true.  (It is possible to preserve eigenvalues if you carefully perform conjugate row and column operations, but I doubt you'll find this useful very often.)

Comment: @Erick So I will perform line operations after i subtract λ and then should I try to create zero elements wherever I can or try to eliminate lambdas?

Comment: @George You could try to eliminate $\lambda$s, but you might start to accumulate some not-so-nice expressions.  You might be better off creating a few zeroes off the diagonal by using row operations with simple coefficients (not much use of $\lambda$), and eventually switch to Laplace expansion.